# Create a new instance on a SQL server, but I need to use the default DB instance

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to connect to mydb\wrk when I already have everything in mydb and I do not want to change anything other than being able to connect to mydb\wrk.

I can connect to my database with the following connection string

```
Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Password = ****; Persist Security Info = True; 
User ID = sa; Initial Catalog = Master; Data Source = MyDb
```

I want to use this:

```
Provider = SQLOLEDB.1; Password = ****; Persist Security Info = True; 
User ID = sa; Initial Catalog = Master; Data Source = MyDb\ wrk
```

I want to change the least possible on the server

Comment: Do you really need a new instance of SQL? Or can you just create a user database called "wrk"? Using the master db for development is not a good idea. Is there a good reason why you are doing this?

Comment: For what possible purpose? To avoid changing a connection string in a config file?

Comment: @Peter  master is only an example

Comment: ...logging in with `sa` is a bad idea and not recommended. Even in a development environment.

Comment: You haven't specified why you cannot do what you are asking about.  Are you asking *how* to install a new instance and move databases to that new instance?

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to install an extra instance if you want to connect to the default instance using an instance name.

You can create an alias for that.

Open SQL Server configuration manager *on the client machine* , and under SQL Server native client configuration for both the 32 and 64 bit node add an alias like this:

[image]

[image]

And then you can connect using your alias name:

[image]

Comment: I had already tried this approach. However I do not know if I'm doing something wrong or if I need to do something else, when I call from inside the Server it works when I try to call from another machine it says that the alias does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

**After your answers that helped me find this solution**:
On the client side
1. Run "cliconfg.exe" from windows run dialog
2. Click "Alias"
3. Click "Add ..." to add the new alias